# Randomly choose an item in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I have the following method that changes my background color to one of three colors:

```
- (void) setBackgroundOfView {
    // change the background color
    UIColor *feijoa = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.565 green:0.82 blue:0.478 alpha:1]; /*#90d17a*/
    UIColor *turquoise = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.78 blue:0.773 alpha:1]; /*#33c7c5*/
    UIColor *lavendar = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.765 green:0.541 blue:0.898 alpha:1] /*#c38ae5*/
    UIColor *randomColor = random.choose(feijoa, turquoise, lavendar) // in pseudocode
}
```

What would be the correct way to do `random.choose(feijoa, turquoise, lavendar)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the colors into a `NSArray` and pick one of them randomly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

- (void) setBackgroundOfView {
    // change the background color
    UIColor *feijoa = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.565 green:0.82 blue:0.478 alpha:1]; /*#90d17a*/
    UIColor *turquoise = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.78 blue:0.773 alpha:1]; /*#33c7c5*/
    UIColor *lavendar = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.765 green:0.541 blue:0.898 alpha:1] /*#c38ae5*/

    NSArray *colors = @[feijoa, turquoise, lavendar];
    int index = arc4random_uniform(colors.count);
    UIColor *randomColor = colors[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of outcomes:

```
  UIColor *feijoa = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.565 green:0.82 blue:0.478 alpha:1]; /*#90d17a*/
  UIColor *turquoise = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.78 blue:0.773 alpha:1]; /*#33c7c5*/
  UIColor *lavendar = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.765 green:0.541 blue:0.898 alpha:1] /*#c38ae5*/
```

And you need to pick one randomly. Put the outcomes into an array:

```
NSArray *choices = @[feijoa, turquoise, lavender];
```

Then pick a random index:

```
int index = arc4random() % ([choices count]);
```

So, choices[index] is your  item

Comment: This is quite similar to Gustavo's approach, but it should be `arc4random() % [choices count]`, otherwise the last item is never selected. Note that according to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html, `arc4random_uniform()` is recommended over `arc4random() % ...` (however it does probably not matter in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I would set up three arrays.  One each for red, green, blue.  then use a random number generator to pick an index.  Then you insert arrayRed[index), arrayGreen[Index], array[Blue]arrayBlue[Index]

```
 UIColor *feijoa = [UIColor colorWithRed:arrayRed[index) green:arrayGreen[Index] blue:arrayBlue[Index] alpha:1];
```

Ue the `arc4Random()` function to generate your index.  This method now allows you to add more colors to your array or different ones easily.

Comment: Are `index`, `Index` and `Blue` the same index? There are also syntax errors in your code.